# NodeJS Как сделать сокеты блокируемыми?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, сокет

Добрый день.

Для общения клиента с сервером использую библиотеку net. Клиент написан на С++ и использует обычные системные сокеты. 
Передаю клиенту множество данных, в виде порций. Заметил, что сервер не дожидается момента, когда клиент получит данные и сразу же отправляет следующий пакет. Из-за этого клиент не обрабатывает задуманную порцию, а соединяет некоторые порции вместе. 
Перед мной стал вопрос: 
Как добиться того, что бы сервер ждал момента - когда пакет дойдет клиенту, и только тогда отправлять следующий пакет. 
Прочитал немного про специфику сокетов, узнал что сокеты могут быть блокируемыми и не блокируемыми. То бишь на нативном уровне есть вроде флага TCP_NO_WAIT, который говорит о том, что не нужно ждать ответа о доставки данных, из-за чего не дожидаясь сразу отправляет следующую порцию.

Так вот, как сделать сокет блокируемым? Чтоб он дожидался ответа о доставки и только тогда отправлял следующий пакет.

Comment: На "порции" придется делить самостоятельно, чтобы вы не настраивали на сервере, по дороге какой нибудь узел может склеить или разбить ваши куски.

Comment: Из решений, где будут готовые "порции" можно посмотреть на вебсокеты.

Comment: Говорят, в JS слово "блокирующий" это страшное ругательство :)

Comment: Блокировка сокета здесь абсолютно не при делах. Как и перевод клиента на вебсокеты ровным счетом ничего не даст. По протоколу websocket данные поступают все равно фреймами. Единственное, так это то, что они уже маркированы и их видны начальные, текущие и конечные фреймы, что позволяет собрать нужную 'порцию'. А транспортом в любом случае является протокол TCP, который и фрагментирует Ваши 'порции'. Поэтому в любом случае Вам нужно самостоятельно контролировать данный процесс. Какой именно способ выбрать - зависит от формата пересылаемых данных.

Comment: Мне нужно передавать картинки разных форматов, в этом то и задача.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. Протокол TCP отправляет непрерывный поток данных, без разбиения на порции. Вам нужно придумать способ разбивать поток на сообщения самостоятельно.

Обычно в таких случаях делают либо особый разделитель между сообщениями (нулевой символ либо перевод строки) - либо же перед сообщением записывают его длину. Второй способ универсальнее.